Mesh looks darker when subdivision is disabled
It seems whenever I am disabling the subdivision the whole mesh become darker.
The File:

Subdivision enabled:

Subdivision disabled:

Why is that?

Hello, maybe it is overlapping with a copy? could you please share your file (at least a part of your object)?

I edited the original post and added the file

Hello, please show the entire node graph of the material used for the model

The split normals (the normals that determine the shading) are messed up for some reason, just Clear Custom Split Normals Data:

